# Zoom Meetings flickering 'lockup' when opening a chat link and zoom is full screen

Tags: zoom-meeting

**Description**: This is kind of an odd one, would appreciate some input. Specifically, when I'm in a full screen zoom call, and I click a link in zoom chat, the link opens up as expected.  When I go back to the zoom, try to close the zoom chat, the screen(s) starts flickering.  Sort of like when you leave something on a key like enter or spacebar, and windows are rapidly opening and closing.  Only way out of it so far, is to restart the computer.

**Setup**: Dell Precision 5750 running Ubuntu 21.04 Using Gnome with Xorg.  External Samsung display connected via a Caldigit TS3+'s DisplayPort.  Firefox: 89.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.21.04.1, MS Edge: 92.0.902.30-1, Zoom: 5.7.26030.0627.  Edge and Zoom were installed from deb downloads from their respective sites.  Firefox was defaulted with Ubuntu.

**Troubleshooting**:

- Tried with both Firefox and Edge defaulted.
- Disabled all gnome extensions.
- Started Zoom NOT fullscreen. This seemed to have the most impact, as now it doesn't do it everytime.
- Zoom test call works flawlessly every time.
- Tried switching to another login prompt and killing the process.  Process was killed, but the effects were still showing on my screen. Just in case my terminology is bad here, I hit `ctrl-alt-f5`, logged in as the same user, then killed the zoom processes.
- Tried without the CalDigit TS3 connected, same result.

If I can provide more information please let me know what I can provide.  It doesn't happen all the time, but I'm probably rebooting twice a day because of it.

Comment: Not that it is at all helpful - you are not alone! I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 Intel CometLake-U UHD graphics with similar issues with zoom.

Comment: This clearly is a bug in Zoom. Your diagnosis is very clear and the issue is easy to reproduce. Have you tried reporting it to Zoom?